# C3 stacked chart maintain data order

Tags: javascript, c3.js

I'm following the instructions from the reference and from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26829384/c3js-bar-chart-with-specific-order), but am having no success.

I've got a stacked bar chart, I want the data in the stack to appear in the order it is in in the data, but it's getting re-ordered and I can't figure out how to prevent it.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gur3q5nt/).

Here's the code

```
var chartOptions = {
  element: 'chart',
  data: {
    "rows":[["0-1","2-3","4-5","6","7"],[25,56,14,2,1],[6,66,27,0,0],[0,70,30,0,0],[27,54,14,5,0],[0,54,30,8,8],[29,64,7,0,0]],
    "type":"bar",
    "groups":[["0-1","2-3","4-5","6","7"]],
    "order":null
  },
  axis: {
    "x":{
      "type":"category",
      "categories":["Whole List","committed","community","congregation","core","crowd"]
    },
    "y":{
      "padding":{
        "top":0
      }
    }
  },
  stacked: true,
  size: {"height":300}
}

var chart = c3.generate(chartOptions);
```

I would like the series to be in the order 0-1, 2-3, 4-5, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a [known issue](https://github.com/c3js/c3/issues/1534). If any one of the headers is an integer (or a string that is an integer), then c3 will sort the columns.

To work around I'm appending a space to the end of the column names so c3 interprets them as a string and not a number.

eg

```
chartOptions['data']['rows'][0] = ["0-1","2-3","4-5",
                                   "6 ", "7 "]; // Spaces appended to these
chartOptions['data']["groups"] = [["0-1","2-3","4-5","6 ", "7 "]];
```

I've updated the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gur3q5nt/1/) with the workaround.