# Data order is not correct in C3 stacked bar chart

Tags: javascript, c3.js

I have a C3 stacked bar chart. In that I am facing an issue. I am plotting 3 values in stack. P1, P2 and Other. If all suppose I dont have value for P2, then my order will change in some random manner.

[image]

See for the second bar P2 is coming on top and P1 is coming below that.

I tried hard coding the 0 to 1, I am getting the correct order.

[image]

How can I correct the order even if some values are zero?

Comment: I checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40911095/c3-stacked-chart-maintain-data-order. But this is not the reason. I am not using the integer column names.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the [data order](http://c3js.org/reference.html#data-order)? I think you will find your answer here.

You can specify `desc`, `asc` or `function (data1, data2) { ... }` to specify the order for the data,  `null` being the order the data loaded.

Please find a working example [here](http://c3js.org/samples/data_order.html).